# Simple program using Pipes hangs

Tags: haskell, haskell-pipes

I have the following program, which produces no output when run with `runhaskell Toy.hs`, and instead hangs indefinitely. By my understanding, the program should print "hi" and then exit. I would appreciate an answer and/or advice about how to debug such an issue. I'm using Pipes 4.0.0 off of github ([github.com/Gabriel439/Haskell-Pipes-Library](http://github.com/Gabriel439/Haskell-Pipes-Library)).

```
module Toy where

import Pipes
import Control.Monad.State

type Request = String
type Response = String

serveChoice :: Request -> Server Request Response IO ()
serveChoice = forever go
  where go req = do
        lift $ putStrLn req
        respond req

run :: Monad m => () -> Client Request Response (StateT Int m) ()
run () = do
    request "hi"
    return ()

main :: IO ()
main = evalStateT (runEffect $ hoist lift . serveChoice >-> run $ ()) 0
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use `foreverK` instead of `forever`, like this:

```
module Toy where

import Pipes
import Pipes.Prelude (foreverK)
import Control.Monad.State

type Request = String
type Response = String

serveChoice :: Request -> Server Request Response IO ()
serveChoice = foreverK go
  where go req = do
        lift $ putStrLn req
        respond req

run :: Monad m => () -> Client Request Response (StateT Int m) ()
run () = do
    request "hi"
    return ()

main :: IO ()
main = evalStateT (runEffect $ hoist lift . serveChoice >-> run $ ()) 0
```

The reason your original version hangs is that you used `forever` in the `Reader` monad (i.e. the `((->) a)` monad) and not the pipe monad.  Within this monad, `forever` is equivalent to `⊥`:

```
-- i.e.        m b  ->     m c
forever :: (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
forever m = m >> forever m
          = m >>= \_ -> forever m
          = \a -> (\_ -> forever m) (m a) a
          = \a -> forever m a
          = forever m
```

`foreverK` is probably what you wanted, since it is the same idiom for `Server`s introduced in the `pipes-3.3.0` tutorial.

This change fixes the program which now completes normally:

```
>>> main
hi
>>>
```

Comment: Where does the Reader monad come into the picture, as I never invoked it explicitly? Is it used internally in Pipes?

Comment: @ajp This behavior is not `pipes`-specific at all.  The compiler infers which monad to use by the context in which you call `forever`.  You accidentally used `forever go` where the compiler was expecting a function of type `Request ->`, not a pipe, so the compiler deduced that the monad you meant was the `Request ->` monad and not the `Server Request Response IO` monad like you intended.